# I'm trying to find out how the GameGuardian speedhack work, but I've come across the unthinkable

Tags: c++, linux

I developed a game, but someone sped it up with GameGuardian. To find out how GameGuardian sped it up, I log out the result of original gettimeofday function, then I modified it by putting the address of the gettimeofday function in a temporary variable, then executed it with that variable and found that the output was actually different! amazing!

the code:

```cpp
typedef int (*go)(timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);

bool MainLoop()
{
    if( !m_terminating )
    {
        go lastgettimeofday = (go)::gettimeofday;
        timeval stime; ::gettimeofday(&stime, NULL);
        long startTime = (stime.tv_sec * 1000) + (stime.tv_usec / 1000);

        timeval stime2; lastgettimeofday(&stime2, NULL);
        long startTime2 = (stime2.tv_sec * 1000) + (stime2.tv_usec / 1000);
        
        // Render frame
        Update();

        timeval etime; ::gettimeofday(&etime, NULL);
        long endTime = (etime.tv_sec * 1000) + (etime.tv_usec / 1000);

        timeval etime2; lastgettimeofday(&etime2, NULL);
        long endTime2 = (etime2.tv_sec * 1000) + (etime2.tv_usec / 1000);

        LOGI( "test", "tDiff1     %d, tDiff2     %d", endTime - startTime, endTime2 - startTime2 );

        float sleepTime = ( 1.0f / (m_targetFps + 2.0f) ) * 1000.0f - tDiff;
        if ( sleepTime > 0 ) usleep( sleepTime * 1000.0f );
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I increased the speed to 9x with GameGuardian, then i get the log:

```
I/test: tDiff1     454, tDiff2     50
```

Comment: It probably intercepts the calls to the clock and returns a different value to your program

Comment: @NathanOliver But why doesn't it intercept when I call it with the address of this function?

Comment: It probably means that you are initializing the function pointer before the "hack" comes in and messes with things. Depending on the compiler/linker settings, that might even happen during compilation.

Comment: Look at the compiled code. (and show us what each got compiled into). The call via a function pointer got compiled into something different than the direct call. The hack library is able to redirect one of the two, but not the other.

Comment: @Frank but i set the function pointer in the `MainLoop()` function

Comment: @Jeffrey There is a lot of code in this xxx.so so the decompiled code is very large, how can I find this piece of compiled code.